# Filtering models in django

Tags: django, model

I am new to django and web frameworks.
I am trying to filter models in django given a substring of its attribute Group

```
pack=My_pack.objects.get(Group=sumthing)
```

now my Group attribute contains a pair of values sepearted by "/"
for eg

```
Group="System/Application"
```

and i want to filter model given only one value suppose "System", then how to do dat????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great place to start would be [The Definitive Guide to Django](http://djangobook.com/). Try checking out the [QuerySet API Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference) in the docs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#icontains

Your code as it stands, won't work. use:

```
pack = My_pack.objects.filter(Group__icontains='System')
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`startswith` field filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#startswith):

```
pack = My_pack.objects.filter(group__startswith='System')
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the syntax for this query:

```
pack = My_pack.objects.get(group__icontains='System')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter in django in different ways,

My_pack.objects.get would bring only one instance , if multiple instance are present here it would give you error. so you need to enclose this into try except blocks.

`pack = My_pack.objects.get(group__icontains='System')`

on the other hand

My_pack.objects.filter would bring more than one instance and if no instance found it would bring and empty list `[]`

`pack = My_pack.objects.filter(group__startswith='System')`

also you can use one of the shortcut functions named `get_object_or_404`. This works similar as get. the difference is you do not need to enclose it in try except block. If it bring the instance it would give the instance as the return value but it does not find any instance then it would throw a 404 status message.

`pack = get_object_or_404(My_pack, group__startswith='System')`